# Test-resources path on Windows in Java unit tests

Tags: java, windows, junit

I'm using this code to get a `Path` for test-resource file in tests code:

```java
Path target = Path.of(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
      .getResource("target1").getFile()
);
```

The file is located at `src/test/resources/target1` and copied on build to `target/test-classes/tartget1`.

It's working fine on Unix-like systems, but on Windows it throws an exception:

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /D:/a/project-name/repo-name/target/test-classes/target1

With the stacktrace (from CI machine):

> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
>       at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
>       at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)

What is the correct way of getting a `Path` in platform-agnostic way? I want to use same code for Unixes and Windows machines. (It's hard to debug this issue for me, because I don't have Windows machine only CI with Windows.)

Comment: What do you need the `Path` for, wouldn't `Class.getResource()` and `Class.getResourceAsStream()` do?

Comment: @Amadán I'm testing the logic of files lookup based on base path. So I don't need to know files content, only file structure

Comment: So it shouldn't be a resource at all. If you really need to do it in a file system and as you're already using `java.nio`, try JimFS–an in-memory filesystem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works on my Windows machine whilst your example also fails as expected:

```
try {
  Path target = Paths.get(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
      .getResource(FILE).toURI());
  System.out.println(target);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I assume this is because parsing a URI has a different implementation than parsing a string.

Comment: Thanks, this code works on Linux and Windows as well